# Problem integrate google firestore with Javafx project

Tags: java, firebase, intellij-idea, javafx, google-cloud-firestore

I have created a Javafx project with IntelliJ idea and want to integrate it with google firestore/firebase. But I am having problem.

I have tried installing google stacklogging driver and google cloud services, both installed successfully. I have tried with this doc https://cloud.google.com/tools/intellij/docs/client-libraries.
Remember, my project is non maven and non gradle.

But, while importing

```
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp;
import com.google.cloud.firestore.Firestore;
```

Error occurs, cannot resolve symbol google.

Comment: why don't you want to use maven or gradle?

Comment: Do you think, it will work smoothly with maven. Because maven projects take more time to build.

Comment: Well, yes, of course, that's why build tools were created! With maven you shouldn't face that issue at all

Comment: No problems! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For further reference

If you are using Maven, add this to your `pom.xml` file

```
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-cloud-bom</artifactId>
        <version>0.79.0-alpha</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
       </dependency>
     </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-cloud-firestore</artifactId>
    <version>0.79.0-beta</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-cloud-logging</artifactId>
    <version>1.61.0</version>
 </dependency>
    ...
```

If you are using Gradle, add this to your dependencies

```
compile 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-firestore:0.79.0-beta'
compile 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-logging:1.61.0'
```

and the full list of services is available [here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-java)